# how to increase loading percentage in SVG?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, svg

I am very new to SVG, I have a SVG already in my theme, it looks like something this.

[image: SVG Image]

The SVG Html looks like this

```html
<div id="apexcharts1q6mbbep" class="apexcharts-canvas apexcharts1q6mbbep apexcharts-theme-light" style="width: 40px; height: 41px;"><svg id="SvgjsSvg1099" width="40" height="41" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev" class="apexcharts-svg" xmlns:data="ApexChartsNS" transform="translate(0, 0)" style="background: transparent;">
    <g id="SvgjsG1101" class="apexcharts-inner apexcharts-graphical" transform="translate(0, 0)">
      <defs id="SvgjsDefs1100">
        <clipPath id="gridRectMask1q6mbbep">
          <rect id="SvgjsRect1103" width="46" height="42" x="-3" y="-1" rx="0" ry="0" opacity="1" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" stroke-dasharray="0" fill="#fff"></rect>
        </clipPath>
        <clipPath id="forecastMask1q6mbbep"></clipPath>
        <clipPath id="nonForecastMask1q6mbbep"></clipPath>
        <clipPath id="gridRectMarkerMask1q6mbbep">
          <rect id="SvgjsRect1104" width="44" height="44" x="-2" y="-2" rx="0" ry="0" opacity="1" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" stroke-dasharray="0" fill="#fff"></rect>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g id="SvgjsG1105" class="apexcharts-radialbar">
        <g id="SvgjsG1106">
          <g id="SvgjsG1107" class="apexcharts-tracks">
            <g id="SvgjsG1108" class="apexcharts-radialbar-track apexcharts-track" rel="1">
              <path id="apexcharts-radialbarTrack-0" d="M 20 4.146341463414631 A 15.85365853658537 15.85365853658537 0 1 1 19.99723301461454 4.1463417048796565" fill="none" fill-opacity="1" stroke="rgba(242,242,242,0.85)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="2.3658536585365857" stroke-dasharray="0" class="apexcharts-radialbar-area" data:pathOrig="M 20 4.146341463414631 A 15.85365853658537 15.85365853658537 0 1 1 19.99723301461454 4.1463417048796565"></path>
            </g>
          </g>
          <g id="SvgjsG1110">
            <g id="SvgjsG1112" class="apexcharts-series apexcharts-radial-series" seriesName="series-1" rel="1" data:realIndex="0">
              <path id="SvgjsPath1113" d="M 20 4.146341463414631 A 15.85365853658537 15.85365853658537 0 1 1 14.061114982430661 34.699256230936875" fill="none" fill-opacity="0.85" stroke="rgba(47,179,68,0.85)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-width="2.439024390243903" stroke-dasharray="0" class="apexcharts-radialbar-area apexcharts-radialbar-slice-0" data:angle="202" data:value="56" index="0" j="0" data:pathOrig="M 20 4.146341463414631 A 15.85365853658537 15.85365853658537 0 1 1 14.061114982430661 34.699256230936875"></path>
            </g>
            <circle id="SvgjsCircle1111" r="14.670731707317076" cx="20" cy="20" class="apexcharts-radialbar-hollow" fill="transparent"></circle>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
      <line id="SvgjsLine1114" x1="0" y1="0" x2="40" y2="0" stroke="#b6b6b6" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" class="apexcharts-ycrosshairs"></line>
      <line id="SvgjsLine1115" x1="0" y1="0" x2="40" y2="0" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="butt" class="apexcharts-ycrosshairs-hidden"></line>
    </g>
    <g id="SvgjsG1102" class="apexcharts-annotations"></g>
  </svg>
  <div class="apexcharts-legend"></div>
</div>
```

I played around `<cicle>` tag but I failed to increase the percentage. Currently you can see the loading icon is around 50% I want to make it dynamic.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please read about [How SVG Line Animation Works](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/)

Comment: Should it work using JavaScript or will it be rendered server side?